# bootstrap date picker current date not highlighting

Tags: jquery

Bootstrap date picker is not highlighting current date on opening calendar.No error is coming. I have tried todayHightlight=true ,but not working. Anyone can point out the problem.

[image]

Code is:-

```
<input type="text" value="" class="datepicker" maxlength="10">
```

And

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({todayHighlight:true});
```

Comment: where is your code. Please create an example link so that we can and let you know. And BTW it's not `Hightlight=true` . It need to be something like this:-`$('#datepicker')
.datepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
    ...
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, make sure you load resources in right order, check console for any errors, try my snippet

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({todayHighlight:true});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" value="" class="datepicker" maxlength="10">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included datepicker.css?

If no then include it.
e.g.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css
```

Comment: <input type="text" value="" class="datepicker" maxlength="10"> $('.datepicker').datepicker({todayHighlight:true});

Comment: From these 2 lines, we can't predict issue. Please try to create fiddle or paste block of code.

Comment: i am using these 2 line .i have not block of code .