# Current date on date picker in vuejs

Tags: datetime, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use the component [vuejs-datapicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker) and I would like to highlight the current day on opening the component.
I am training using this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mpklq49wp

To sum up:

1. I am looking for something similar to what happens here ([bootstrap date picker current date not highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42409970/bootstrap-date-picker-current-date-not-highlighting)) but using vuejs.
2. How to also choose the color of this date independently of the selected day.

As I am a beginner in vuejs I don't know how to do it.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will be helpful https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker#highlighted-dates

For example, you can use `dates` array with single value = current date

```js
const highlighted = {
    dates: [
      // your date
      new Date(2016, 9, 18)
    ]
}
```

```html
<datepicker :highlighted="highlighted"></datepicker>
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped me a lot. But do you know how to change the color or the form (like a circle around the current day)?

Comment: Highlighted cell has ```class="cell day highlighted"``` I think you should play with it